# Is there a way to get the statistics of data in legal hold through graph API?

Tags: .net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, o365security-compliance

I am currently working on eDiscovery [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-case-post-legalholds?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) through graph API and I want to know if there is a way of getting statistics of data that is put on legal hold

Attached an image below and the statistics I am looking for (image is from compliance.microsoft.com)

[image]

Can we get the statistics from below through any graph API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know `legalHold` id you can use the ID of `legalHold` resource for the eDiscovery case.

You can call

```
GET /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/sourceCollections

var sourceCollections = await graphClient.Compliance.Ediscovery.Cases["{ediscovery.case-id}"].SourceCollections
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

to get list of [sourceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/ediscovery-sourcecollection?view=graph-rest-beta).

For each `sourceCollection` you can run an [estimate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-sourcecollection-estimatestatistics?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) of the number of emails and documents in the source collection

```
POST /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/sourceCollections/{sourceCollectionId}/estimateStatistics

await graphClient.Compliance.Ediscovery.Cases["{caseId}"].SourceCollections["{sourceCollectionId}"]
.EstimateStatistics()
.Request()
.PostAsync();
```

The response will contain a `Location` header, which contains the location of the [estimateStatisticsOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/ediscovery-estimatestatisticsoperation?view=graph-rest-beta) that was created to handle the estimate.

Or you can get the [last estimateStatisticsOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-sourcecollection-list-lastestimatestatisticsoperation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) object associated with a source collection.

```
GET /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/sourceCollections/{sourceCollectionId}/lastEstimateStatisticsOperation

var estimateStatisticsOperation = await graphClient.Compliance.Ediscovery.Cases["{caseId}"].SourceCollections["{sourceCollectionId}"].LastEstimateStatisticsOperation
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

`estimateStatisticsOperation` contains the properties `status`, `siteCount`, `mailboxCount`, `indexedItemCount`, `indexedItemsSize`, `unindexedItemCount` and
`unindexedItemsSize`.